Zeroes of $\Im(\text{cd}(x|i))+\Re(\text{cd}(x|i))$
Can someone help to determine the zeroes of this function in $0 < x < 10$ range? I need the analytical expressions, not numerical values.
$$\Im(\text{cd}(x|i))+\Re(\text{cd}(x|i))$$
here $\text{cd}$ denotes the Jacobi elliptic function cd.
I am particularly interested in the one which is located near $x = 7$.
Here is the plot:

I need this for solving a definite integration problem which I posted here.
